# Республика Бурятия

Tags: морфология

Как правильно склоняется название административно-территориальной единицы *Республика Бурятия*? "В Республике Бурятии" или "в Республике Бурятия"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только "в Республике Бурятия".
Как и везде в подобных случаях. 
Единственный случай, когда наблюдается колебание - Федеративная республика Германия. Это, видимо, обусловлено историческими причинами, подробно здесь не стоит.

Answer (score 2):

Однозначный ответ: в Республике Бурятии, Республике Болгарии и т.д.
Предыдущий ответ неправильный.

Comment: Ну что Вы (говорите)? Правильнее писать "в Республике "Бурятия", но потом решили не усложнять дело и писать так, как предлагает @behemothus